# Try to sort date (dd/mm/yy) of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, sorting, date

Now I am using jquery datatable to display some data. The only problem is when I sort the column date (dd/mm/yy), it is not correct. Tried a few ways that doesn't work. Here are the codes.

```
$('#eventtable').dataTable({
                data: jdata.aaData,
                bDestroy: true,
                bRetrive: true,
                bProcessing: true,
                searching: true,
                // set columns
                columns: [
                   { data: "NAME" },
                   { data: "DATE", "type": "date-uk" },
                   //{ data: "POSTCODE" },
                   //{ data: "LOCATION" },
                   { data: "ADDRESS" },
                   {
                       data: "WEBSITE",
                       render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                           if (type === 'display') {
                               return $('<a target=_blank>')
                               .attr('href', data)
                               .text('More details')
                               .wrap('<div></div>')
                               .parent()
                               .html();
                           } else {
                               return data;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                ],
            });
```

Now the date column has the data type "dd/mm/yy" already. But sorting effect seems like it is according to the string not the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <div>
</div>

var dateArray = new Array();
dateArray.push("12/12/2011");
dateArray.push("12/12/2013");
dateArray.push("12/12/2012");
dateArray.sort();
dateArray.sort(function(x, y){
      date1 = new Date(x.date);
      date2 = new Date(y.date);
      return date1 - date2 ;
  })
$.each(dateArray,function(index,op)
{
    $('div').append(dateArray[index] + "<br>");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/462d5pqj/